# How to store HTML text into variable (capybara/ruby)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara

Please, I'd like to store the value 337 from bellow code to a variable.

```html
<div class="if-search-block-head">
  
  <h3 class="department-title">Electronics</h3><a href="?fq=C:4791&amp;fq=DN:Eletrônicos&amp;ft=tv&amp;PS=20&amp;mm=100" tabindex="" class="btn btn-primary department-button">All 337 results</a>

</div>
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Try this: `page.find('.if-search-block-head a').text` if this gives you the text `All 337 results`

Comment: I doesn't. It says there are more result:

Capybara::Ambiguous: Ambiguous match, found 5 elements matching css ".if-search-block-head a"

Comment: Actually you have 5 elements with the same class, so either assign a different class if you need  a particular div result or just choose first, second index just like an array.

Comment: `page.first('.if-search-block-head a').text`. This assumes that the link will always be the first `<a>` in its parent element.

Answer (score 0):

To complete the answer to your question, best use 2 steps.

1. Get the text (Like [Deep](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4207394/deep) and [max](https://stackoverflow.com/users/544825/max) explained)

   text1 = page.first('.if-search-block-head a').text
2. Grep the number from the text

   count = text1.scan(/All (\S+) results/).last.first